# Updating MySql using AJAX in jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code and the SELECT is working correctly to pull in the form data, however, the UPDATE statement is not working.  Any suggestions on what could be corrected to make it work would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    include 'includes/config.php';
    require_once('includes/auth.php');

    if ( isset( $_GET['aj'] ) && $_GET['aj'] == '1' ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET['ax']) && $_GET['ax'] == 'education_details' ) {
            $sql = 
<<<SQL
                                        SELECT  * 
                                        FROM    education 
                                        WHERE   id = '{$_GET['rid']}'
                                        ORDER BY date_completed DESC
SQL;
            $sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Get education detail error: " . mysql_error());

            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result) ) {
                $education_info = array(
                    'member_id' => $row['member_id'],
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'degree' => $row['degree'],
                );
            }

            echo json_encode($education_info);
        }
        exit;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['aj']) && $_POST['aj'] == '1' ) {
        if (isset( $_POST['ax']) && $_POST['ax'] == 'save' ) {
            $sql=
<<<SQL

                    UPDATE  education
                    SET     name =              '{$education_info['name']}',
                            degree =            '{$education_info['degree']}'
                    WHERE   id =                '{$education_info['rid']}'

SQL;
        }

        // echo json_encode($education_info);
        exit;
    }


?>  
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#accordion').accordion({ 
                header: "h3", 
                collapsible: true,
                active: false
            });

            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                open: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 525,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    } 
                }
            });


            $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');

            });

            education_details.initialize();
        });
        var education_details = {
            url : '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>',
            initialize : function() {
                            $('#dialog_edit').dialog({
                                autoOpen: false,
                                open: true,
                                modal: true,
                                width: 525,
                                buttons: {
                                    "Save" : function() {
                                        $.post("educationie.php", {"aj":"1", "ax":"save" , "rid":$(this).attr("id")}, function(data) {
                                            alert(data);
                                        }, "json");
                                    //  $(this).dialog('close');
                                    },
                                    'Cancel': function() { 
                                        $(this).dialog('close'); 
                                    } 
                                }
                            });
                            $('.edit_open').click(education_details.open);

            },
            open :   function() {
                        $('#dialog_edit').dialog('open');
                        $.get(education_details.url, {"aj":"1","ax":"education_details","rid":$(this).attr("id")}, education_details.education_details_success, "json");
                     },
            education_details_success : function(data) {
                                            $("#dialog_edit input[name=name]").val(data.name);
                                            $("#dialog_edit input[name=degree]").val(data.degree);
                                        }


        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    if ( $_POST['ax'] == "new" ) {

        // echo "DID IT GO HERE"; exit;


        $sql=<<<SQL

                INSERT INTO education (member_id, name, degree)
                VALUES      (
                            '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}',  
                            '{$_POST['name']}', 
                            '{$_POST['degree']}'
                            )

SQL;


        if(mysql_query( $sql ) or die ( "Insert failed." . mysql_error()) );

        // echo $sql; exit;


        // header( "Location: education.php");
    }


?>

    <button id="dialog_link" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Add New</button>
    <br>    

    <div id="dialog" title="Add New" style="display:none;">

        <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ax" value="new">
        Institution<br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
        Degree(s) Earned<br><input type="text" name="degree" /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="submit" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all"/>

    </div>


    <div id='dialog_edit' title='Edit' style="display:none;">
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
        Institution<br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
        Degree(s) Earned<br><input type="text" name="degree" /><br>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div id="accordion">

    <?

        $sql = mysql_query("    SELECT  * 
                                FROM    education 
                                WHERE   member_id = '" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "' 
                                ORDER BY date_completed DESC");




        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){





            echo    "<h3><a href=#>" . $row['name'] ."</a></h3>";
            echo    "<div> 
                            <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign='top'>

                                    <a id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" class=\"edit_open\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">Edit</a>

                                    <br> Degree(s): ". $row['degree'] . 
                                    "</td>
                                    <td style='padding-left:85px;'>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>    
                    </div>";


        }
        mysql_close($con);

        ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting error_reporting(E_ALL) and checking the errors in firebug...

the update references an undefined variable:

```
$education_info['name']}'
```

it wasn't set at that point, you probably want to use $_POST['name'] or something instead

(you might want to bind parameters in queries as it's easier as well)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post the RID = where id

```
        <?php
            include 'includes/config.php';
            require_once('includes/auth.php');

            if ( isset( $_GET['aj'] ) && $_GET['aj'] == '1' ) {
                if ( isset( $_GET['ax']) && $_GET['ax'] == 'education_details' ) {
                    $sql = 
        <<<SQL
                                                SELECT  * 
                                                FROM    education 
                                                WHERE   id = '{$_GET['rid']}'
                                                ORDER BY date_completed DESC
        SQL;
                    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Get education detail error: " . mysql_error());

                    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result) ) {
                        $education_info = array(
                            'id' => $row['id'],
                            'member_id' => $row['member_id'],
                            'name' => $row['name'],
                            'degree' => $row['degree'],
                        );
                    }

                    echo json_encode($education_info);
                }
                exit;
            }

            if ( isset($_POST['aj']) && $_POST['aj'] == '1' ) {
                if (isset( $_POST['ax']) && $_POST['ax'] == 'save' ) {
                    $sql=
        <<<SQL

                            UPDATE  education
                            SET     name =              '{$_POST['name']}',
                                    degree =            '{$_POST['degree']}'
                            WHERE   id =                '{$_POST['rid']}'

        SQL;
                }
                $sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Get education update error: " . mysql_error());

                // echo json_encode($education_info);
                exit;
            }


        ?>  
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
        <head> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" /> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#accordion').accordion({ 
                        header: "h3", 
                        collapsible: true,
                        active: false
                    });

                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        open: true,
                        modal: true,
                        width: 525,
                        buttons: {
                            "Cancel": function() { 
                                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                            } 
                        }
                    });


                    $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');

                    });

                    education_details.initialize();
                });
                var education_details = {
                    url : '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>',
                    initialize : function() {
                                    $('#dialog_edit').dialog({
                                        autoOpen: false,
                                        open: true,
                                        modal: true,
                                        width: 525,
                                        buttons: {
                                            "Save" : function() {
                                                $.post("<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", {"aj":"1", "ax":"save" , "rid":$("#dialog_edit input[name=rid]").val(), "name":$("#dialog_edit input[name=name]").val(), "degree": $("#dialog_edit input[name=degree]").val()}, function(data) {
                                                    alert(data);
                                                }, "json");
                                               $(this).dialog('close');
                                            },
                                            'Cancel': function() { 
                                                $(this).dialog('close'); 
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $('.edit_open').click(education_details.open);

                    },
                    open :   function() {
                                $('#dialog_edit').dialog('open');
                                $.get(education_details.url, {"aj":"1","ax":"education_details","rid":$(this).attr("id")}, education_details.education_details_success, "json");
                             },
                    education_details_success : function(data) {
                                                    $("#dialog_edit input[name=name]").val(data.name);
                                                    $("#dialog_edit input[name=degree]").val(data.degree);
                                                    $("#dialog_edit input[name=rid]").val(data.id);
                                                }


                };
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>

        <?php
            if (!empty($_POST['ax']) && $_POST['ax'] == "new" ) {

                // echo "DID IT GO HERE"; exit;


                $sql=<<<SQL

                        INSERT INTO education (member_id, name, degree)
                        VALUES      (
                                    '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}',  
                                    '{$_POST['name']}', 
                                    '{$_POST['degree']}'
                                    )

        SQL;


                if(mysql_query( $sql ) or die ( "Insert failed." . mysql_error()) );

                 //echo $sql; exit;


                // header( "Location: education.php");
            }


        ?>

            <button id="dialog_link" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Add New</button>
            <br>    

            <div id="dialog" title="Add New" style="display:none;">

                <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ax" value="new">
                Institution<br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                Degree(s) Earned<br><input type="text" name="degree" /><br>
                <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="submit" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all"/>
                </form>

            </div>


            <div id='dialog_edit' title='Edit' style="display:none;">
                <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="rid">
                Institution<br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                Degree(s) Earned<br><input type="text" name="degree" /><br>
                </form>

            </div>


            <div id="accordion">

            <?

                $sql = mysql_query("    SELECT  * 
                                        FROM    education 
                                        WHERE   member_id = '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}' 
                                        ORDER BY date_completed DESC");




                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){





                    echo    "<h3><a href=#>" . $row['name'] ."</a></h3>";
                    echo    "<div> 
                                    <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign='top'>

                                            <a id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" class=\"edit_open\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">Edit</a>

                                            <br> Degree(s): ". $row['degree'] . 
                                            "</td>
                                            <td style='padding-left:85px;'>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>    
                            </div>";


                }
                mysql_close($con);

                ?>
            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```